# Error encountered in starting Kafka zookeeper application start script

Tags: apache-kafka

I am seeing an error when I am starting Zookeeper service on windows using command prompt in admin mode. Can somebody assist with this error.

Running the following command in the bin folder:

```
zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Results in the below error:

> "this file does not have an app associated with it for performing this
> action . Please install an app or, if one is already installed ,
> create an association in the default apps settings page"

Comment: Did you mean running "zookeeper-server-start.bat" instead of "zookeeper-server-start.sh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `zookeeper-server-start.bat` on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am still experiencing error when I am running this command. bin/zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties